# Blender 3.4 OBJ 100X scale issue while export/import to/from other applications

Tags: export, transforms, import, obj

I am trying to exporting models from blender to import in Marvelous Designer 12. Both application's unit setup is set at Centimeter. But still object appears 100X smaller in MD then Blender.

Tested in 3DSMax also and same issue in both applications. It seems like Blender unit is 100X smaller/larger then others.

Is this known issue? Has anyone have solution for this?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome. If this is indeed a bug, we won't be able to help and you will need to report the bug here https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I cannot confirm that this is a bug (I may also be mistaken). I have just tested this with Blender 3.4 and Marvelous Designer 12. Note: You also have the possibility to set the scaling when exporting in Blender, and also to influence the scaling in Marvelous Designer when importing.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple (although it may be a bug in Blender):

Just use a different scaling (*m* instead of *cm (DAZ Studio)*) when importing into Marvelous Designer:

[image]

Or use other scaling settings when exporting from Blender:

[image]

By the way, the problem does not exist if you use FBX format instead of OBJ (more recommended in this case).

Comment: thanks for sharing! :)